Библиотека easyocr не видна
Не работает библиотека easyocr, по идее установлена,  перезапускал ide не помогало, устанавливал через терминал - снова не помогало...



Проверьте как называется файл вышей программы, если easyocr.py переименуйте.

да, easyocr.py...

@чистов_n, ответы - в ответы.

Предупреждения (пока не ошибки) на последнем скриншоте: 1 - неиспользуемый импорт. Начните код писать, который будет импортируемый модуль использовать - предупреждение уйдет. 2 - файл импортирует сам себя. Переименуйте файл. 3 - нет переноса строки в конце файла. Просто добавьте перенос строки.

@Qwertiy О'кей!

Ваша проблема в том что ваш файл называется так-же как и библитека:

Import resolves to its containing file

То есть ваша программа пытается импортировать саму себя.
Что-бы решить проблему вам надо переименовать файл во что-нибудь другое. Например test_easyocr.py
